# Add attribute to element which has an attribute with a particular value

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a regex expression that will add an attribute to an element which already has a attribute with a particular value.

for e.g:

```
<meta name="stack" />
```

I want to add an attribute to the meta element which has an attribute name="stack" such that it will look like

```
<meta name="stack" value="overflow" />
```

Also some C# code for match and replace will help.

I cannot use XmlDocument or HtmlAgilityPack due to malformed xml in input.

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch. Adding attributes is not trivial with regex and should really be done with a parser of some kind. Are you sure there aren't any options besides regex? It could get quite hairy. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(<\s*meta\s+name\s*=\s*"stack")(\s*/>)
```

replace with

```
$1 value="overflow" $2
```

Comment: how could I do this irrespective of position of attribute for example if another attribute before name="stack" like <meta x="y" name="stack"

Answer (score 2):

Start with the following regular expression...

```
<meta[^>]+name="stack"
```

And replace with...

```
$0 value="overflow"
```

The `$0` in the replace string represents the entire match.  Then you're just appending `value="overflow"` to the end of that.

Here's a working example...

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=586c2040-8700-4ea2-a146-1477ca1bcb62

Just click the ".NET" button at the top of Regex Hero to see the .NET code for this.  Or here's a simplified version...

```
return Regex.Replace(text, @"<meta[^>]+name=""stack""", @"$0 value=""overflow""");
```